# Regex - replace method to remove operator from string produce undesired result

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string in which i want to replace `operator like (+, -, /, *)`, so that i am able to separate expressions.

```js
var exp = '9 + 3 - 7 / 4 * 6.56';

// current output 9 3 7 4 6 56
// desired result 9 3 7 4 6.56
document.body.innerHTML = exp.replace(/ /g,'').replace(/[+-\/\*]/g, ' ');
```

But, `replace()` method returns an undesirable result.

Comment: think about negative numbers as well.

Comment: Accepted @Amit answer because there is no -ve number in my case. Also, i only need to find out the number array. But it would be great if anyone can provide a solution with negative number as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-` signifies a *range* in character-class in regex. Either put it at the beginning or at the end or escape it.

```
document.body.innerHTML = exp.replace(/ /g,'').replace(/[+\/*-]/g, ' ');
```

Comment: Thanks @amit. I didn't notice that.

Comment: @MohitPandey happens :)

Comment: how to handle negative numbers?

Answer (score 4):

You could reduce your code like,

```
exp.replace(/\s*[-+\/*]\s*/g, ' ');
```

In some cases unescaped hyphens `-` at the middle of character class would act like a range operator. So you need to escape the hyphen or you need to put it at the start or at the end of the character class.

Example:

```
> var exp = '9 + 3 - 7 / 4 * 6.56';
> exp.replace(/\s*[-+\/*]\s*/g, ' ');
'9 3 7 4 6.56'
```

If the input contain negative number , i assumed that it would like in the below format.

```
> var exp = '-9 + 3 - 7 / 4 * -6.56';
undefined
> exp.replace(/\s+[-+\/*]\s+/g, ' ');
'-9 3 7 4 -6.56'
```

Answer (score 1):

Split based on operator that is in between digits for considering **negative numbers** as well.

```
(?!=\d) [-+*/] (?=\d|-)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rG6cY3/5)

It uses [**Look Around**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to look behind and ahead for digit around operator.

It works for negative numbers as well for example  `-9 + 3 - 7 / 4 * 6.56`

[Find more...](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=regex+split+math+equation+based+on+math+operator&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=NsifVMGmNYOXuATR0oLICQ)

Comment: Thanks just a slight change `(?!=\d) [+\-*\/] (?=\d|-)`

Comment: Thanks @Braj for regex with -ve number as well.